# I nedd to use this code (See more...) more than one time in one page

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to add (see more) in all the pragraph in the same page however when I add the code more than one time, its work only in one pragraph any help?

```
function showHide(shID) {
  if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
  document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
    }
else {
  document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
  document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
}
  }}
```

HTML CODE

```
<p>
 <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');">See more...</a>
</p>
<div id="example" class="more">
  <p>Extra words.....</p>
  <p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');">Hide.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.more {
 padding:0 3px 0 0;
 display: none;
 border: 1px solid #666;
}
a.showLink, a.hideLink {
text-decoration: none;
color: #36f;
padding-left: 8px;
background: transparent url('down.gif') no-repeat left;
}
a.hideLink {
background: transparent url('up.gif') no-repeat left;
}
a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #36f;
}
```

only I can use it one time.

how can I use it more than one time in the same page?

Comment: How are you trying to use it more than once on the page?  Your code only shows you using it for the `'example'` div, which you've said works.  Are you correctly changing the IDs that you pass into the `showHide` function?

Answer (score 3):

you should change the id's, i guess that you paste the same code over and over, without changing the id's:

```
<p>
<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');">See more...</a>
</p>
<div id="example" class="more">
    <p>Extra words.....</p>
    <p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');">Hide.</a>
    </p>
</div>

<p>
<a href="#" id="example-show2" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example2');">See more...</a>
</p>
<div id="example2" class="more">
    <p>Extra words.....</p>
    <p><a href="#" id="example2-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example2');">Hide.</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `id="example-show2"` and `onclick="showHide('example2')` ?

Comment: the onclick is the reference, not the id of the link

Comment: sure, I was thinking `example2-show` would be more logical, but it doesn't matter as long as it's unique.

Comment: indeed, it would be more logical to re-use attributes, but hey, we didn't write the code ;-)